# "largely transshipping goods produced elsewhere"--participle clause or shortened relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses, participle-clauses

> A century ago, Carribean, Chinese, and African ports were open for trade and served as flourishing entrepôts, **largely transshipping goods produced elsewhere.** (
> From　https://eml.berkeley.edu/~eichengr/research/brooking.pdf )

Should the bold part considered as a participle clause or a shortened relative clause?
How do I discern each?

Comment: It's a gerund-participial clause functioning as a supplementary adjunct. It can't be a supplementary (non-defining) relative clause since it would be impossible to insert a relative phrase.

Comment: I think I can rewrite it as "and African ports were open for trade and served as flourishing entrepôts, which largely transshipping goods produced elsewhere. " in which the antecedent of the relative clause is "flourishing entrepôts"

Comment: No, you can't. Your suggestion is ungrammatical.  Relative clauses are finite, but "which largely transshipping goods produced elsewhere" is non-finite because it doesn't have a finite verb.

Comment: sry, I actually want to rewrite it to "and African ports were open for trade and served as flourishing entrepôts, which largely transhipped goods produced elsewhere."　where there is a finite verb.

Comment: The non-finite clause in your original example is a supplementary adjunct with "flourishing entrepôts" as anchor. Your suggested example is a supplementary relative clause (the finite equivalent of the original) with "flourishing entrepôts" as anchor/antecedent. I would avoid using the term 'reduced/shortened' relative clause.